# What is the hitting probability $f_{ij}$ where $i=j$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

E.g. What is $f_{22}$?

Intuitively I just think this is simply equal to $1$. Surely the probability of hitting $2$ is certain if I'm already at $2$. I'm not sure how to justify this rigorously though, so I don't know if I'm correct.

So my question is, is this probability equal to $1$? If so, how do you justify it?

Comment: It all depends on how you define $f_{ij}$, either $$f_{ij}=P(\exists n\geqslant0,X_n=j\mid X_0=i)$$ and then $f_{ii}=1$, of course, or $$f_{ij}=P(\exists n\geqslant1,X_n=j\mid X_0=i)$$ and then $f_{ii}<1$ is quite possible.

Comment: @Did Thank you, that answers my question.